# AttributeError: function 'viOpen' not found

Tags: python, pyvisa

My code starts like this

import pyvisa as visa
import os

rm = visa.ResourceManager('C:\Program Files (x86)\IVI Foundation\VISA\WinNT\agvisa\agbin\visa32.dll')
my_connect = rm.open_resource("USB0::0x2A8D::0x0B0B::MY47191118::0::INSTR")

I am trying to control my Keysight Signal Analyzer using VISA.

When I try to run my python code it throws me this error.

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\kolap\Downloads\MeasurementControlCode\MeasurementControlCode\scan_signal_analyzer.py", line 45, in

rm = visa.ResourceManager('C:\Program Files (x86)\IVI Foundation\VISA\WinNT\agvisa\agbin\visa32.dll')

File "C:\Users\x\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pyvisa\highlevel.py", line 2992, in **new**
visa_library = open_visa_library(visa_library)

File "C:\Users\x\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pyvisa\highlevel.py", line 2904, in open_visa_library
return cls(argument)

File "C:\Users\x\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pyvisa\highlevel.py", line 191, in **new**
obj._init()

File "C:\Users\x\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pyvisa\ctwrapper\highlevel.py", line 172, in _init
functions.set_signatures(self.lib, errcheck=self._return_handler)

File "C:\Users\x\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pyvisa\ctwrapper\functions.py", line 324, in set_signatures
apply(

File "C:\Users\x\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pyvisa\ctwrapper\functions.py", line 226, in *internal
set_signature(library, function_name, argtypes, restype, errcheck*)

File "C:\Users\x\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pyvisa\ctwrapper\functions.py", line 418, in set_signature
func = getattr(library, function_name)

File "C:\Users\x\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\ctypes_*init*_.py", line 389, in **getattr**
func = self.**getitem**(name)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\x\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\ctypes_*init*_.py", line 394, in **getitem**
func = self._FuncPtr((name_or_ordinal, self))

AttributeError: function 'viOpen' not found

So the info for pyvisa is as shown in the image
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Yt2K.png)